Can you algebraically prove that a hexagon with glued opposite edges is a torus?
I understand how a square, with $1$ vertex, $2$ edges, and $1$ face has a Euler characteristic that matches as torus $(0)$. For a hexagon, I assume with gluing opposite edges we have $3$ edges. The hexagon is one face, thus we must have only $2$ vertices for $2-3+1=0$. I am not understanding how the hexagon will only have $2$ vertices though, and what distinguishes the difference between a vertex $v_1$ against $v_2$ of this hexagon.

Enumerate hexagon vertices as $v_1\dots v_6$, say, counterclockwise. The edge $v_1v_2$ is glued to $v_4v_5$, identifying the vertices $v_1 \sim v_5$. But we also glue the edge $v_6v_1$ to $v_3v_4$, identifying $v_1\sim v_3$. So,  $v_1$, $v_3$ and $v_5$ all turn into a single vertex after gluing. The same happens for $v_2\sim v_4 \sim v_6$.
This, in the end you end up with just two vertices.

You can view this hexagon as a regular hexagon tiling the plane (effectively taking the quotient of the plane by this tiling). A vertex in the tiling (after the "gluing") corresponds to 3 vertices on the unglued hexagon, with 3*120° = 360°. The same reasonning works when gluing opposite edges of a square.

One way of seeing this easily is to consider the lattice $L\subseteq\mathbb C$ spanned by the 6th roots of unity.  This is sometimes referred to as the hexagonal lattice, because the fundamental domain given by the Voronoy region of the origin is precisely a regular hexagon.
The quotient $\mathbb C/L$ is of course the torus, since the lattice is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$ as a group.
